# Reading input file IloCplex C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, multidimensional-array, cplex

I am trying to read my data file which includes a matrix like this: [[10, 5, 3],[3, 5, 6][2, 1, 1]]

and try to solve the developed model by Calling cplex solver.  When I compile the code, I get the error: Out of bounds operation: index superior to size of array; assertion failed". How can I fix this problem ? Thank you in advance

```
#include<ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
#include <fstream>
ILOSTLBEGIN
typedef IloArray<IloNumArray> FloatMatrix;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    IloEnv env;
    const char* filename ="C:/.../.../.../.../Project.dat";
    FloatMatrix p(env);
    if (argc > 1)
        filename = argv[1]; 
    ifstream file(filename);
    file.open("Project.dat");
    if (!file.is_open()) {
      `cerr << "ERROR: could not open file '" << filename << "' for reading" << endl;`
      throw(-1);
}
    file >> p >>;
    cout << p<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can fix this problem by using your debugger to run your program, one line at a time, which lets you inspect the values of all variables and observe as they change while the program executes, and analyze your program's logical flow this way. This is what a debugger is for, and using a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. Have you tried running your program in a debugger, and if not why not? What did you observe, in your debugger, as the reason for the error? P.S. The shown code cannot possibly compile, due to apparent syntax errors.

Comment: Why are you opening `file` two times?

Comment: @Damien, I made a mistake while writing question, it was commented in the original code